# Bicubic block in Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

While working with the code of [SRGAN](https://github.com/deepak112/Keras-SRGAN/blob/master/Network.py), I wanted to replace `UpSampling2D` by `tf.image.resize_bicubic`. I used keras lambda layer for this function, as below

```
def bicubic_lambda(input_shape, scale=2):
    shp = input_shape
    def outshape(input_shape):
        dims = [input_shape[0],input_shape[1] * scale,input_shape[2] * scale,input_shape[3]]
        output_shape = tuple(dims)
        return output_shape
    
    def bic(x):
        return image.resize_images(x, [shp[1]*scale,shp[2]*scale], method=image.ResizeMethod.BICUBIC)
        
    return Lambda(bic, output_shape=outshape, name='bicubic_lambda')
```

it trains well with out any error but the issue is that I can not save the model. the `generator.save(model_save_dir + 'gen_model%d.h5' % e)`
causes an error  `TypeError('Not JSON Serializable: %s' % (obj,))`
The code works find with UpSampling2d. my tf version is 1.14.0 and keras 2.3.1. please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a one liner solution.

```
model = Lambda(lambda image: tf.image.resize_images(image, (image.shape[1]*2, image.shape[2]*2), method = tf.image.ResizeMethod.BICUBIC))(model)
```